# Value-of select in <a href=> (XSLT)

Tags: xslt

I try to concstruct link with

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('file:///', substring-before('%RolesPath%', 'roles'),'Flores.chm')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  Help
</xsl:element>
```

but I get error:

> *File file:///Flores.chm not found*

I'm pretty sure, that variable %RolesPath% works fine. I'm using it in code normally. And if I use in code only

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('file:///', substring-before('%RolesPath%', 'roles'),'Flores.chm')"/>
```

I get

> file:///C:\Flores\Flores.chm

which is right path. Where I'm doing mistake please?

edit. %RolesPath% stores path to specify folder of program, which works with this code. In my case %RolesPath% stores "C:\Flores\roles\".

To specify my problem. I need open file(Flores.chm) in root folder of program. Program can be install everywhere in PC and prapably only way, how I can get the path is via %RolesPath%.

Comment: What is `%RolesPath%`? Are you using that as a placeholder instead of what's actually there? If so, could you show us what's actually there, since that's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: @JLRishe I edit my previous post with more detailed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are passing to `substring-before()` is just a string (`'%RolesPath%'`). It appears that you are trying to use a Windows environment variable. This isn't going to work the way you're using it.

I think you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

Pass the value of the environment variable as an `xsl:param` when you call the stylesheet. This would work in either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

You would need the `xsl:param`:

```
<xsl:param name="RolesPath"/>
```

and this is how you would reference it:

```
<a href="{concat('file:///', substring-before($RolesPath, 'roles'),'Flores.chm')}"/>
```

---

**Option 2**

Use the `environment-variable()` function. *This would only work with an XSLT 3.0 processor, such as Saxon-PE or EE.*

Example:

```
<a href="{concat('file:///', substring-before(environment-variable('RolesPath'), 'roles'),'Flores.chm')}"/>
```

Here's another example of `environment-variable()` to show the function actually working:

*XSLT 3.0*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <environment-variable name="TEMP" value="{environment-variable('TEMP')}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Output* (when applied to any well-formed XML)

```
<environment-variable name="TEMP" value="C:\Users\dhaley\AppData\Local\Temp"/>
```

Comment: I'm working in XSLT 1.0 and Option 1 by you doesn't work. %RolesPath% isn't Windows variable, it's application variable in program, in which I work.

Comment: @Sk1X1 - Then you need pass `%RolesPath` as an `xsl:param` to your stylesheet. The XSLT processor has no idea what `%RolesPath%` is.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this shorter expression**:

```
<a href="file:///{substring-before($RolesPath, 'roles')}Flores.chm"/>
```

where `$RolesPath` is passed as an external, global parameter to the transformation.

**How exactly to pass an external parameter to the transformation varies from one XSLT processor to another** -- read your XSLT processor documentation. Some XSLT processors also allow string-typed parameters to be passed to the transformation from a command-line execution utility.

Comment: This doesn't work. Still same error. It seems like program variable %RolesPath% doesn't work in <a> atribut.

Comment: @Sk1X1, There is no `%RolesPath%` in my answer. Maybe you wanted to comment on some other answer?

Comment: Comment is right. It was more like specification, why my code doesn't work.
If I used your code, I can't use $RolesPath, 'cause variable $RolesPath  don't exist. I have to use %RolesPath% instead of $RolesPath.

Comment: @Sk1X1, I clearly say in this answer, that you must pass the value of the `$RolesPath` parameter externally. You need to read the documentation of your XSLT processor how you can pass an external parameter to a transformation.